# Lower and Upper Sum of a Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm working through a question and seem to have hit a brick wall with my manipulation. I know I am right up to the point where I am stuck but I will show my working anyway.

My question

By choosing a suitable dissection of $[1, 3]$ ,show that $\int^3_1 2x^2 -1 dx$ exists and find its value.

My suitable dissection is $[1,1+\frac{2}{n},1+\frac{4}{n}...,1+\frac{2n}{n}]$

From there I started working out the upper sum $s^u$ and the lower sum $s_l$ ,

$s_l$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n (2(\frac{2i-2}{n})^2-1)\frac{2}{n}$

After manipulation I got to

$16\sum^n_{i=1} \frac{i^2-2i+1}{n^3}+\frac{i-1}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n}$

and fo the upper sum

$s^u$= $\sum_{i=1}^n (2(1+\frac{2i}{n})^2-1)\frac{2}{n}$

After manipulation I got to:

$16 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i^2}{n^3}+\frac{i}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n}$

I then have been given the tip that $\sum^n_{i=1} i^2 = \frac{n^3}{3}+ \frac{n^2}{2}+ \frac{n}{6}$

There is probably a blatant solution here but I am unable to see it, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you having trouble working out those sums? Note that, for example, $$\sum_i{i^2-2i+1\over n^3}=n^{-3}(\sum_ii^2-2\sum_ii+\sum_i1)$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am yes although that is not the problem, once I have broken down the sums as you suggest I am not surre what to do with $ 2 \sum_i i + \sum_i 1 $

Comment: Surely you can work out $\sum_{i=1}^n1$, if you understand what $\sum_{i=1}^n$ means. Is that the problem, that you have never seen summation notation before?

Comment: For given real numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, the notation $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ is equivalent to $a_1+\cdots+a_n$.